# Having null result whenever using dom selectors in spfx webpart

Tags: spfx, reactjs, react-webpart, dom-manipulation

[image]Trying to get the tsx video tag duration by selecting the tsx tag through dom selectors but getting null in the console

Comment: You are trying to access the video element before adding it to DOM, hence you are getting null result.

Comment: Can you suggest any solution to prevent this?

Comment: What is the requirement behind getting the video duration? Do you need the video duration on page/component load or later on button click (or something else)?

Comment: I need the video duration and currentTime to get the remaining time of the video.